# Translate "Link text" in View

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have the following text/token in one of my field's "Link text" field.

"Download [file:name]"

How do I translate "Download"

Here is a screenshot:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwquchykaymh20j/Screenshot%202014-05-28%2023.15.14.png

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **Locale** module enabled, you can translate the string on the page *admin/config/regional/translate/translate* - just search for Download and the string should appear in the translatable strings.

In order to translate the string you have to open the actual page once to let drupal register the translatable string.

Comment: This answer is only half correct. Adding a string translation doesn't automatically translate the string without use of the t() function.